# Core Data setPrimitive-setter causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, core-data, exc-bad-access

when I try to set the variable `eventId` of my `NSManagedObject (Event)` I get ther error `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. 
I don't know the reason.

Here's the code of my class `Event`

```
@interface Event : NSManagedObject 

@property (assign)              NSInteger   eventId;

@end


@interface Event (PrimitiveAccessors)
- (NSInteger)primitiveEventId;
- (void)setPrimitiveEventId:(NSInteger)event_id;
@end



@implementation Event
@dynamic eventId;

...

-(NSInteger)eventId
{
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"eventId"];
    NSInteger id = [self eventId];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"eventId"];
    return id;
}

-(void)setEventId:(NSInteger)event_id
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"eventId"];
    [self setPrimitiveEventId:event_id]; //Here I get the error
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"eventId"];
}

...
```

Anyone can solve the problem?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look closely at [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001919-SW13), you'll see that the primitive accessor methods for the scalar attribute `double length` in the example still use `NSNumber *` arguments and return values:

```
@interface MyManagedObject (PrimitiveAccessors)
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *primitiveLength;
@end
```

[Note: I added the `*` that was missing in the original code snippet in Apple's documentation.]

So try declaring your primitive accessors with `NSNumber *` arguments and return values.

Or if you really must, consider [implementing your own primitive accessor methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002154-SW5).

Comment: you are right...I have to us NSNumber*. The solution is at my answer

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
@interface Event (PrimitiveAccessors)
- (NSNumber *)primitiveEventId;
- (void)setPrimitiveEventId:(NSNumber*)event_id;
@end

-(NSInteger)eventId
{
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"eventId"];
    NSNumber *id = [self primitiveEventId];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"eventId"];
    return [id integerValue];
}

-(void)setEventId:(NSInteger)event_id
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"eventId"];
    [self setPrimitiveEventId:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:event_id]];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"eventId"];
}
```